Angular dependency injected classes: how to hold different information in a single class
I am quite new to this so apologies if these are obvious questions, but I have not found a answer from Googling.
My Angular application needs to access data from a large number of JSON files. These JSON files all have identical schemas. I only need to have two or three to be available at once. I access the necessary files via AJAX. These files are wrapped in a repository pattern.
Without DI I could create a single repository class with multiple instances of it, one per JSON file. With DI I cannot do this because the class is a singleton.
Do I have to create a class per JSON file instead? I want to avoid this because it mean if more JSON files are added in future, I also need to add more classes rather than it just being a data change.
Example (sorry I am on a train so this is an example off the top of my head)
JSON files:
dog-names.json
[
    "Doggy",
    "Thor"
]

human-names.json
[
    "Steve",
    "Katie"
]


Repository service:
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
external class SpeciesRepository {
    private data: string[];
    
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    load(speciesType: string) {
        this.data = this.httpClient.get<string[]>('assets/' + speciesType + '.json');
    }

    getByIndex(index: number):  {
        return this.data[index];
    }
}

This service would then be used by multiple other services (with some extra code to handle only loading the data on one - but I essentially pre-load the data behind a "loading" screen.)
In a non-DI this would work ok (although I guess speciesType would be better as a constructor argument). However, as the injected class is a singleton in DI it is not going to work because of the class level data variable.
I did wonder if I could solve this by removing providedIn, but from what I can tell this is still not safe.
In a DI do I have to do something like the following for each JSON file? Or am I misunderstanding something conceptually?
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
external class DogRepository extends SpeciesRepository {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
        super(httpClient);
    }

    override load() {
        super.load('dog');
    }
}

Thank you for your help.
EDIT to add some context
I am writing a procedurally generated turn based dungeon crawler, but using Angular (I realise this is an odd thing to do, but a job I start soon is for a company that uses Angular so I wanted to try it in an interesting way) and trying to use a something similar to a DDD pattern (i.e. repository services in an infrastructure layer, logic services in an application layer, components in a presentation layer). A simplified flow is as follows

Step 1: Display "generating dungeon map" component - inject all animal species repositories the procedural generation decided to use for this map and load their JSON (e.g. human, dog, cat).
Step 2: Display first "room" component - inject an animal species repository per animal species in the room (e.g. human, dog) - already loaded by step 1.
Step 3: As player progresses, display next "room" component - inject an animal species repository per animal species in the room (e.g. human, cat) - already loaded by step 1.


you don't need one class per json, you can use the same class for all if you have the same data structure for each json.

I am not sure how to inject them though? If I need SpeciesRepository for both human and dog, how do I inject it twice, once for human and once for dog? Won't the injection mean SpeciesRepository is effectively a singleton so if have it load the human JSON it will have that data everywhere, whether I intended to use is for human or dog?

you can have 1 class for the json loader, a 2nd class for a json file and a 3rd class for a json element. and then the loader is a singleton. how do you use the json datas in your application ?

That's what I am basically doing at the moment. Injecting a class that creates the repository instances (with an interface for the JSON schema). It's just not very tidy to unit test. However, in order to avoid each component getting its own instance, the injected class needs to keep a cache of the instances. That way the repository instance only makes the HTTP request for the JSON when when it is first used; it does not need to repeat this when the instance is used again. (I guess it is really a repository of repositories.) I'll update the post with some context. And thank you for your help.

It's not obvious questions, but you need "re-thinking" when you use Observables.
Angular httpClient.get is an Observable. An Observable is "something" that you need subscribe to get the values
When you makes
this.data = this.httpClient.get<string[]>('assets/' + speciesType + '.json')

in this.data you have NOT the value of your json file, else a "subscription" to the observable. In general the services return observables and we subscribe in components. The reason it's that you can not know when really you have the data, e.g.
So, you can think in something like
init(speciesType: string) 
{
    this.httpClient.get<string[]>('assets/' + speciesType + '.json')
                                    .subscribe((res:string[])=>{
                                                 this.data=res;
                                    })
}

getByIndex(index: number):  {
    return this.data[index];
}

But, in this case this NOT work
//in your component
//NOT work
ngOnInit()
{
   this.myservice.init()
   console.log(this.myservice.getByIndex(0)) //possible undefined
}

You can convert to Promise an observable and use await but really it's not a good idea.
I suggest, if you want to preload declare a subject and subscribe to the subject in the component
ready$=new Subject<boolean>=new Subject()
init(speciesType: string) 
{
    this.httpClient.get<string[]>('assets/' + speciesType + '.json')
                                    .subscribe((res:string[])=>{
                                                 this.data=res;
                                                 this.ready.next(true)
                                    })
}

Now, in your component you can do
//see that if you use "public" you can use in the .html
constructor(public service:DataService){}
ngOnInit(){
   this.service.ready$.subscribe((res:boolean)=>{
        if (res)
             console.log("Ready!!")
   })
}

Of use in the .html
<div *ngIf="service.ready$|async else #loading">
...
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
...loading..
</ng-template>


Thanks for your response. (I'm aware of how RxJS works.) The root of this is I only want to load subset of otherwise identical schemaed JSON files (for performance reasons) so my data is split many files. Because I am using a repository pattern and my repos are injected, I need a repo per file - the repo is a singleton so cannot hold the data from more than one file (the data has been pre-loaded in by a loading component / service). I'm pretty sure the correct way is to have multiple repos with a common base, but I wanted to try using metadata to define the repos and their files.
